# Is ContinueWith in c# truly asynchronous?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Using ContinueWith on the task I executed is suppose to run asynchronously, but is it really asynchronous? I mean if I run a task "t" and use that task to call say
t.ContinueWith(t=>t.Result), will this be run asynchronously? I know it won't block all the threads till result is complete but will it completely return the handle back to the caller or will it do context switching between threads.

Answer (score 2):

> Using ContinueWith on the task I executed is suppose to run asynchronously, but is it really asynchronous?

Yes.

> I mean if I run a task `t` and use that task to call say `t.ContinueWith(t=>t.Result)`, will this be run asynchronously?

Yes.

> I know it won't block all the threads till result is complete but will it completely return the handle back to the caller or will it do context switching between threads.

I don't know what handle are you talking about. What `ContinueWith()` does is to schedule the *continuation* to execute when the `Task` completes and then immediately returns.